# Codeigniter RESTful API not returning JSON

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, backbone.js, rss

I have this application where I use Codeigniter as backend and Backbone as frontend. Now I use the RESTful API from https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver. I want to fetch RSS feeds, so I created a RSS-model.php in `application->models`:

```
<?php
    class Rss_model extends CI_Model
    {
        var $table_name = 'artist_news';
        var $primary_key    = 'news_id';

    function get_all_rss_feeds()
    {
        $this->db->select($this->primary_key);
        $this->db->from($this->table_name);
        return $this->db->get();
    }

   }
?>
```

and then in `application->controllers` I created the folder `api` in which I created the file rss.php:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class rss extends REST_Controller{

public function get_all_rss_feeds_get()  
{ 
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('rss_model');

    $data = $this->rss_model->get_all_rss_feeds();

    if($data) {
        $this->response($data, 200); 
    } else {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any news!'), 404);
    }
 }
}

?>
```

So far so good, it returns an array of text with a lot of rss-feeds, but NOT in `JSON` format, which I need for my frontend.

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Thanks in advance...

**[EDIT]**

My Backbone Code looks like this:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var Rss = App.module();

    Rss.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'rss',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render)
        },
        serialize: function() {
            return this.collection ? this.collection.toJSON() : [];
        }
    });

    Rss.RssCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function() {
            return '/myproject/index.php/api/rss/get_all_rss_feeds/';
        }
      });

    return Rss;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt this work ? http://example.com/books?format=json

Answer (score 3):

go to config/rest.php file and find this line :

```
$config['rest_default_format'] = 'xml';
```

change it to :

```
$config['rest_default_format'] = 'json';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the result in return in the model please check below

```
function get_all_rss_feeds()
{
    $this->db->select($this->primary_key);
    $this->db->from($this->table_name);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are usign the Phil Sturgeon REST library you need to append the format type in the URL. Example:

```
http://example.com/books.json
http://example.com/books?format=json
```

If you want it in another format, let's say XML, you just need to pass the new format in the URI, doesn't need to change anything in your code. Example:

```
http://example.com/books.xml
http://example.com/books?format=xml
```

Further reading:

Content-Type Section - https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: ok, I'm pretty new to this, so how can I apply this? In my `REST_Controller.php` I already set the format to `JSON`

Comment: @SHT All you need to do is to add a `.json` to the end of the URL you are calling. If you are calling `localhost/rss/some-method` adding the `.json` to the end will look something like this `localhost/rss/some-method.json`, try that and let me know.

Comment: Ok I tried to add `.json` but no effect! I added my backbone code to my question, maybe that helps?!

Comment: @SHT did your copy the file `Format.php` to your `application/libraries` folder? and did you copye the file `rest.php` to the `application/config` folder? Please review that those files are there and then make the request with the `.json` or `?format=json` ath the end.